# Get bytes from a short long in C18

Tags: pic, c, software, compiler, c18

I'm using the C18 compiler and need to get the three bytes of a `short long` from MSB to LSB. I'd say I could use this:

```
void theFunction(unsigned short long input) {
    doSomething((input>>16) & 0xff);
    doSomething((input>>8) & 0xff);
    doSomething(input & 0xff);
}
```

But now my code isn't working (does compile, but doesn't run as expected). I do not know where the problem is, so can anyone confirm that *this* code works?

Comment: a byte is 0xff long not 0x0f. Anyways, this is a nice example where it comes in handy to look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: @jippie thanks, miscopied that from my code. Fixed now.

Comment: @Camil You're right, my bad.

Comment: The code calls `doSomething` three times, first with the highest byte, second with the middle byte, and third with the lowest byte.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks, that's what I wanted to hear - can you make it an answer?

Comment: as long as doSomething expects an unsigned char it should do exactly what you want it to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code calls `doSomething` three times, first with the highest byte, second with the middle byte, and third with the lowest byte.